# Factory and non factory method

Tags: magento2

here you can see i am loading my helper 2 ways one is factory and second non factory but i dont know what will be the advantage if i call it through factory and non factory please help me to understand this difference thanks.

```
\My\Basic\Helper\DataFactory $helper,
        \My\Basic\Helper\Data $helpers)
```

Answer (score 0):

This is not related to magento directly. Factory is a design pattern which is allowing you to gain abstraction and loose the strong coupling of the code which makes it easier to maintain. Meaning if you change the class code you don't need to change it everywhere mater as you call it with the factory abstraction level.